# Random color generator that generates colors that can be visibly differentiated in TCL

Tags: tcl

Does anyone knows how do I generate a bunch of random colors without them looking too similar that it can't be differentiated by the human eye?

I'm able to generate random color codes using the following:

```
    set r [expr { int(256 * rand()) }]
    set g [expr { int(256 * rand()) }]
    set b [expr { int(256 * rand()) }]

    set newColor [format "#%02x%02x%02x" $r $g $b]
```

Then I'll use the 'if' condition to ensure that the color codes generate does not repeat. After that I'm kind of stuck.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should find this of interest! http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating colors that are meant to be visually distinctive, the cheapest method is to pick random values from the HSV colorspace and then convert them to RGB. There's some nice code for doing the conversion in [the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/19711) and you'd integrate that with your own code rather like this:

```
proc getRandomColor {} {
    set h [expr { int(256 * rand()) }]
    set s [expr { int(256 * rand()) }]
    set v [expr { int(256 * rand()) }]

    lassign [hsvToRgb $h $s $v] r g b

    return [format "#%02x%02x%02x" $r $g $b]
}

set newColor [getRandomColor];   # I find it's best to make such bits into procs
```

Now, this is not *guaranteed* to generate colors that are distinctive, but it does tend to reduce the problem. If you need to stick to vibrant colors, reduce the variation in the S and V channels (i.e., pick smaller random ranges) and ***be aware*** that color isn't accessible; make sure that color-coded information is also conveyed in different ways as well.

Comment: Thank Donal. Picking random values from HSV is a great idea. However, I'm not sure if it's my problem, I think that there are some bugs in the link provided. When h=8, s=221, and v=109, hsv2rgb returns me {27904 -6138880 -6138880}. Think this link would be a better one http://www2.tcl.tk/19711

Comment: @Mich: Yes, that seems to work better. Will edit my answer to use the better link

Answer (score 2):

I would take a slightly different approach. For one, you should know that each person differentiates colours differently, and that women seem to be able to distinguish more colours than men. See the XKCD colour survey for an entertaining read on this. http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/ So, despite the literally millions of possible colours in the RGB space, we are reduced to only being able to distinguish them into a few dozen groupings (blues, reds, greens etc).

I would start with a list of colours that I know that I can distinguish e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names 
Create a list of all the RGB with these e.g.

```
set colours [list "F0F8FF" "FAEBD7" "00FFFF"]
```

Then just randomly pick a colour from your list:

```
set num_of_colours [llength $colours]
set my_colour_index [expr { int($num_of_colours * rand()) }]
set my_colour [lindex $colours $my_colour_index]
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. It's a great idea. But I can't control the amount of colors required. As a result, the amount might exceed the amount of color in the color list I create.

Comment: @Mich you're welcome, but I think you're back to your original problem of generating colours that can't be differentiated by the human eye. I thought that was what you were trying to avoid?

Comment: And of course, there are much longer lists available than the link I provided in my answer e.g. http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm